# Laravel required_unless validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have an problem using `required_unless` validation.

What I want to do is say that `building name` is required when `building number` is **empty** or other way round so `building number` is required when `building name` is **empty**. At the moment it requires both.

```
public function rules(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('entity_id');
    $entity = Entity::with('address')
        ->find($id);
    $validation = $entity->id;
    return [
        'name' => 'required|alpha_special|unique:entities,name,'.$validation.'|min:3|max:30',
        'type' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:entities,email,'.$validation,
        'building_name' => 'alpha|required_unless:building_number,value',
        'building_number' => 'numeric|required_unless:building_name,value',
        'street' => 'required|alpha_spaces',
        'town' => 'nullable|alpha',
        'city' => 'nullable|alpha',
        'postcode' => 'required|max:8',
        'telephone' => 'required|telephone',
        'ical' => 'nullable|active_url',
    ];
}
```

view:

```
<div class="hidden multi form-group{{ $errors->has('building_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                          <div class="building_name_message form-control alert-warning" style="display: none;"></div>
                            <label  id="building_name_label" for="building_name" >Building Name</label>
                            <input  id="building_name" type="text" class="form-field form-control" placeholder="Building name (If applicable)" name="building_name" value="{{ old('building_name') }}">
                              @if ($errors->has('building_name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('building_name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                              @endif
                          <div class="building_number_message form-control alert-warning" style="display: none;"></div>
                            <label  id="building_number_label" for="building_number" >Building Number</label>
                            <input  id="building_number" type="text" class="form-field form-control" placeholder="Building Number (If applicable)" name="building_number" value="{{ old('building_number') }}">
                              @if ($errors->has('building_number'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('building_number') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                              @endif
                              <div class="form-navigation">
                                <button type="button" class="previous btn btn-info pull-left">&lt; Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" id="next" class="next btn btn-info pull-right">Next &gt;</button>
                              </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to place **null** instead of **value** in validation for empty value check.

```
'building_name' => 'alpha|required_unless:building_number,null',
'building_number' => 'numeric|required_unless:building_name,null',
```

Another way is to use `required_without` as :

```
'building_name' => 'alpha|required_without:building_number',
'building_number' => 'numeric|required_without:building_name',
```

See docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-without)

**UPDATE**

Since above validations check `alpha` and `numeric` type for `building_name` and `building_number` respectively, You can change the order of the validation rules so that it will check `required_without` at first and doesn't checks value if it doesn't present.

```
'building_name' => 'required_without:building_number|alpha',
'building_number' => 'required_without:building_name|numeric',
```

This might work in your case.

Hope, You understand.

Comment: however it is still validating and not letting it throught for building_name when it is null. It says building_name.alpha' => 'House/Building name can only contain letters' this error message.

Comment: You can change the order of validation as `required_without` at first and then `alpha`.

Comment: I did try that and it still throws me an error, I will update my question with relevant view for that page

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas I've updated. Try this one might work for your case.

Comment: I did it like in the update and it still throws me the error

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas In your input field, if you have spaces on the text then validation will fail.

Comment: well there is no spaces because bulding_name is empty I only input building_number and it fails

Comment: I've similar case before but I have get out with above way but I wonder why this not working for you.

Comment: Basically what happens is when I input number it says name can only contain etc when I enter building name and leave number empty it says, that it can only contain numbers

Comment: and what is to validate for required_without all the time, but only validay alpha or numeric when there is input, if it's null ignore it

Comment: Have you tried last one I have posted. Otherwise you might have some issues with cache.

Comment: yeap I did try the lat one you have posted

Comment: Some other people here might give you solution. Best of luck bro

Answer (score 2):

you should use `required_without` according to your requirement as

```
'building_name' => 'alpha|required_without:building_number',
'building_number' => 'numeric|required_without:building_name',
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> **required_unless:anotherfield,value,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty unless the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

That doesn't sound like what you need (well technically it can work if "value" is set to "null" but what's the point?), the next one however does:

> **required_without:foo,bar,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any of the other specified fields are not present.

```
'building_name' => 'alpha|required_without:building_number',
'building_number' => 'numeric|required_without:building_name',
```